# У меня не работает смена анимации с ходьбы на анимацию покоя в Unity3D, C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Использовал Animator, вот фото:https://i.stack.imgur.com/rucr5.jpg. Код такой:
'''

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerAnim : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator anim;
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();  
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))

        {
            anim.SetFloat("Blend", 0.5f);
        }

        else
        
        {
            anim.SetFloat("Blend", 0f);
        }
    }
```

}'''

ПОМОГИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА!!!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости неправильно установлено дерево в аниматоре
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

тот параметр, что вы изменяли на скриншоте совсем для другого нужен